# Get count of a value that repeats ONLY in different users

Tags: mysql, distinct

I would like to get the number of times a `fruit` is repeated BUT only when the `user` is different

| fruitid | user | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 180 | 217 | watermelon |
| 1a6 | 2dd | apple |
| 1cf | 2ac | orange |
| 1da | 2dd | orange |
| 1f3 | 2dd | banana |
| 1a6 | 2dd | apple |
| 220 | 1da | banana |
| 254 | 2dd | apple |
| 2a0 | 2ac | apple |
| 2a5 | 229 | apple |

I tried with this query, but the output is not the expected one for several reasons

```sql
SELECT
  user,
  fruit,
  count(fruit) appearancesOfTheFruitAtDifferentUsers
FROM fruitBox
GROUP BY user
HAVING appearancesOfTheFruitAtDifferentUsers > 0
```

However:

- It does not show me how many times a fruit was repeated with a different user in the tables
- Suppresses several user-fruit rows; they should all appear with their respective count

| user | fruit | appearancesOfTheFruitAtDifferentUsers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1da | banana | 1 |
| 217 | watermelon | 1 |
| 229 | apple | 1 |
| 2ac | orange | 2 |
| 2dd | apple | 4 |

I have tried some suggestions from comments, but there was no success.

The output I would like to obtain is:

| user | fruit | appearancesOfTheFruitAtDifferentUsers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 217 | watermelon | 1 |
| 2dd | apple | 3 |
| 2ac | orange | 2 |
| 2dd | orange | 2 |
| 2dd | banana | 2 |
| 1da | banana | 2 |
| 2dd | apple | 3 |
| 2ac | apple | 3 |
| 229 | apple | 3 |

Here, the count for `apple` is 3, because it appears for 3 different users. `watermelon` is 1 because it only appears once. `Orange` and `Banana` are each used by 2 users, so their count is `2`.

In addition, I would also like to delete row #6 (excluding the table header) as it is a duplicate fruit in the same ID

In a few words, I want the table to show how many times a fruit is repeated in different users and if there is a user with two equal fruits, it only shows one in the table.

Comment: Please include the expected output as well?

Comment: Why does `signup` have a total of `3` in some places but `2` somewhere else? Please show input data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just edited the post, I already included it

Comment: @Bohemian I have just edited the post, I am already showing the input and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL version support window function, you can try `COUNT` window function.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, 
          type, 
          count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY type) c 
    FROM logs
)t1
WHERE c > 1;
```

| user_id | type | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17ea9b33e6f | signup | 5 |
| 17ea9c0e9ce | signup | 5 |
| 17ea9d21366 | signup | 5 |
| 17ea9e04dc7 | signup | 5 |
| 17ea9e04df8 | signup | 5 |
| 17ea27674d1 | work | 2 |
| 17ea27674d8 | work | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: ORDER BY in window definition for COUNT() makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me, the output was very strange and far from what I want to achieve. I just edited the post to make it more understandable if you want to check it out

Answer (score 0):

The database term for "different" is `distinct`, and this term is also an SQL keyword.

Join the table to a subquery that provides the count of distinct users having that fruit:

```
select 
  user,
  t.fruit,
  fruit_user_count
from mytable t
join (
  select
    fruit,
    count(distinct user) fruit_user_count
  from mytable
  group by 1
) c on c.fruit = t.fruit
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b562e27/1).